# Save figure using default stylesheet?

Tags: export

I'm using the following to export a figure as .eps for use in latex:

```
p4 = Plot[ Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}]
myExportForLatex[filename_, image_, allowRast_ : False] :=
 Module[{output, dir}, dir = Directory[];
  output = {Export[filename <> ".eps",
     First[ImportString[
       ExportString[image, "PDF", "AllowRasterization" -> allowRast,
        Background -> None], "PDF"]]],
    Export[filename <> "pn.png", image,
     "AllowRasterization" -> allowRast, Background -> None,
     ImageResolution -> 72*4]};
  {dir <> "/" <> output[[1]], dir <> "/" <> output[[2]]}]

myExportForLatex[ "SinPlotFig1", p4 ]
```

The export function above was the end result of [a discussion on "best way to export figures from Mathematica"](https://plus.google.com/u/0/103302026148070112829/posts/YtM2TERTpob), and works well provided the stylesheet being used is the default. If I'm using a different stylesheet, for example, the report stylesheet, this method saves the figure with stylesheet specific background, like so:

[image: test plot]

This is after running:

```
epstopdf SinPlotFig1.eps --outfile=SinPlotFig1.pdf
```

so that I can use the .pdf in my latex code.  Notice that the background has the pink of the report stylesheet, as well as the 3-sides black bounding box.

How can this export method be modified to effectively use the default stylesheet when exporting the .eps figure?

Comment: How about temporarily changing your notebook's style to Default, doing the export, and changing it back to your original style?

Comment: That's what I've done, but was asking in hopes of a better way.

Comment: Can you give us an idea of what you would consider better? Without some idea of what constitutes "better", your question is too broad IMO.

Comment: A programmatic way to set the stylesheet that is in effect for the export, so that the figure is created as if it was done with the default stylesheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might define

```
newStyleSheet = (SetOptions[InputNotebook[], StyleDefinitions -> #]&)
```

and then insert the lines

```
newStyleSheet["Default.nb"]
```

and

```
newStyleSheet["Report.nb"]
```

in the appropriate places in `myExportForLatex`. The second call of `newStyleSheet` being made to revert to your normal style.

Comment: I've added:

sty = CurrentValue[ InputNotebook[], StyleDefinitions ] ;

If [ sty == "Default.nb", Null, SetOptions[ InputNotebook[], StyleDefinitions->"Default.nb" ] ] ;

...

If [ sty == "Default.nb", Null, SetOptions[ InputNotebook[], StyleDefinitions-> sty ] ] ;


to my function.  It makes the notebook flash while the file is being saved, which is a bit weird seeming, but it works.

Comment: I believe there is a syntax error in that first statement.  the '}' shouldn't be there.  SE only allows edits of 6+ characters so maybe the original author has to fix it.

Comment: @user1816847. You are right. Thanks for pointing it out to me. I have edited the answer to correct the error.