# Unable to make Inset background transparent

Tags: graphics

The following code is the minimal version I managed to create. With my Mathematica 11.0.1.0 on Ubuntu 14.04 I find with the code that there is some background for the Inset graphics that can not be made transparent. Is there a way to do this?

```
Show[
  Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}], 
  Graphics[
    Inset[
      Graphics[{Green, Disk[]}, Background -> None],
      {0.5, 0.5},
      {0, 0},
      0.2,
      Background -> None
    ],
    Background -> None
  ],
  Background -> None
]
```

In this specific case it is about removing the white space between the plotted line and the circle.

If I export the graphics as a pdf I get the following result with a gray background that I don't want. In Mathematica itself it manifests itself as a whitespace.

[image]

**Edit:** Happens with the Stylesheet StandardReport and not with a style-less notebook.

Comment: What white space? Can you make it more clear?

Comment: I don't get any gray background when I export to `pdf` on `Windows 10`. `MMA` version is `10.4`

Comment: No problems in v10.1.0 under Windows.  Both the standard output and export to .GIF look as they should.

Comment: And what about the small whitespace between the circle and the line in Mathematica itself?

Comment: No problems with version 11.0.0 on Windows 7x64. Acrobat renders exported PDF as expected.

Comment: No problem on MMA 11.0 on OSX.

Comment: Seems to be only (or at least) happening with Stylesheet StandardReport, can someone confirm this?

Comment: @Maikel Yes, with *StandardReport* I can reproduce this.  With that critical detail I believe this question is a duplicate of: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/78522/121

Comment: Related: [(45362)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45362/121)

Comment: Also related: [(118830)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/118830/12)

Answer (score 2):

You've got background from the stylesheet. Please try to remove it by using `BaseStyle` directive:

```
  g = Show[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}], 
      Graphics[
          Inset[
            Graphics[{Green, Disk[]}, Background -> None], 
            {0.5, 0.5}, {0, 0}, 0.2, Background -> None, 
            BaseStyle -> {Background -> None}], 
   Background -> None], Background -> None]
```